# How to locate the directory where the sum of the number of lines of regular file is greatest (in bash)

Tags: bash, unix

Hi i'm new in Unix and bash and I'd like to ask q. how can i do this

> The specified directory is given as arguments. Locate the directory
>   where the sum of the number of lines of regular file is greatest.
>   Browse all specific directories and their subdirectories. Amounts
>   count only for files that are directly in the directory.

I try somethnig but it's not working properly.

```
 while [ $# -ne 0 ];
  do case "$1" in 
         -h) show_help ;; 
         -*) echo "Error: Wrong arguments" 1>&2 exit 1 ;; 
         *) directories=("$@") break ;; 
esac 
shift 
done

IFS='
'
amount=0
for direct in "${directories[@]}"; do
    for subdirect in `find $direct -type d `; do
       temp=`find "$subdirect" -type f -exec cat {} \; | wc -l | tr -s " "`
       if [ $amount -lt $temp ]; then
            amount=$temp
            subdirect2=$subdirect
       fi
    done
    echo Output: "'"$subdirect2$amount"'"
done
```

the problem is here when i use as arguments this dirc.(just example)

```
/home/usr/first and there are this direct. 
/home/usr/first/tmp/first.txt (50 lines) 
/home/usr/first/tmp/second.txt (30 lines) 
/home/usr/first/tmp1/one.txt (20 lines)
```

it will give me on Output `/home/usr/first/tmp1 100` and this is wrong it should be `/home/usr/first/tmp 80`

I'd like to scan all directories and all its subdirectories in depth. Also if multiple directories meets the maximum should list all.

Comment: What's the problem? In what way does it not work properly?

Comment: This script seems to work for me.  Only problem that I see is I do not know how the directories array is getting set.

Answer (score 1):

Given your sample files, I'm going to assume you only want to look at the immediate subdirectories, not recurse down several levels:

```
max=-1
# the trailing slash limits the wildcard to directories only
for dir in */; do
    count=0
    for file in "$dir"/*; do
        [[ -f "$file" ]] && (( count += $(wc -l < "$file") ))
    done
    if (( count > max )); then
        max=$count
        maxdir="$dir"
    fi
done
echo "files in $maxdir have $max lines"
```

```
files in tmp/ have 80 lines
```

Comment: I'd like to scan all directories and all its subdirectories in depth. Also if multiple directories meets the maximum should list all.

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of Unix (caugh), here's an absolutely disgusting chain of pipes that I personally hate, but it's a lot of fun to construct `:)`:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=- | tail -1 | { read a _ && echo "$a $1"; }' _ {} \; | sort -nr | head -1
```

Of course, don't use this unless you're mentally ill, use [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552)'s [nice answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744928/how-to-locate-the-directory-where-the-sum-of-the-number-of-lines-of-regular-file/19746582#19746582).

You can have great control on find's unlimited filtering possibilities, too. Yay. But use glenn's answer!